# Running Android App From Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-lvl

I'm trying to do some troubleshooting for an app that was made by another programmer in Eclipse for the Android store. The app has already been published: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giantastronaut.fieldsoflight&hl=en

I'm trying to run it on the computer it was created on, but when I run it on the either the emulator or an actual phone I get this message:

"Application not licensed"
Unable to validate license. Check to see if a network connection is available.

Any ideas how I can get this to play? (I am very new to Android app development, so I am well aware this could be a very simple error on my part.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much a solution as it was a workaround... I found another version of the project that seems to start up without a problem. It looks like some files were moved around manually and may have caused the problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you see, its a paid app. So, you need to buy the app to get the license for using the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a paid application and is most likely using Google's Licencing Service to prevent users who have not bought the application from accessing the application. Google Licensing service can check the status at runtime to prevent usage, Take a look at it more [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html)

Comment: The licensing process makes sense. But I'm using the actual Eclipse project the app was created from on my computer. When I run it from the project on the emulator or an actual phone it gives me that license warning. Is there a way to disable this check so I can work on the program?